# How can I use a type from a stitched schema in my local schema

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a GraphQL schema that uses stitching to include a remote schema alongside a locally defined schema.

My stitching logic looks like this:

```js
  const link = new HttpLink({
    uri: config.cms.endpoint,
    fetch,
  });

  const remoteSchema = await introspectSchema(link);

  const remoteExecutableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema: remoteSchema,
    link,
  });

  const localExecutableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [
      localExecutableSchema,
      remoteExecutableSchema,
    ],
  });

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: mergedSchema,
    ...
```

The imported `typeDefs` variable includes this definition:

```graphql
  input OrderItem {
    alphaId: ProductAlphaId!
    addOns: [ProductAlphaId]!
  }
```

The `remoteSchema` contains the definition for `ProductAlphaId`. However, as it is defined in the "remote" schema, not the local one, I get the error when starting the server:

```
Could not start server: Unknown type "ProductAlphaId".
```

How am I supposed to use types from one schema in another? I understand this could potentially create circular dependencies, but in my case I only want to use types from the "first" schema in the "second".

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue, you need to check the order of the schema while merging.

```js
...

const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [
      remoteExecutableSchema,
      localExecutableSchema
    ],
  });

...
```